# How to detect when the image appears in PictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

I have a problem about System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox. I want to show a image on monitor and capture it on the camera. So I use Winform which include a picturebox. The picture box is:

```
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
pb.WaitOnLoad = true;
```

When I set a bitmap to PictureBox and capture the image from camera,

```
// Show bmp1
this.image.Image = bmp1;
this.image.Invalidate();
this.image.Refresh();

// Delay 1s
UseTimerToDelay1s();

// Show bmp2
this.image.Image = bmp2;
this.image.Invalidate();
this.image.Refresh();

// Capture
CaptureImageFromCamera();
```

It only capture the bmp1.

If I add a small delay like this,

```
this.image.Image = bmp2;
this.image.Invalidate();
this.image.Refresh();
UseTimerToDelay100ms();
CaptureImageFromCamera();
```

It capture bmp2. The Image set method seem to be a async method. Does any method to confirm the image is set? Thanks.

Comment: So you want to double check that the image was set, after you set it? Not `bool isSet = this.image.Image == bmp2;`?

Comment: What are `UseTimerToDelay1s()`, `UseTimerToDelay100ms()`? Maybe, make the current method/handler `async` and `await Task.Delay([An interval in ms])`. Using a Timer, you won't delay anything, unless it's the Timer tick/elapsed event itself that sets the new Bitmap

Comment: @John: I just edit the post to provide more information. So what I want is to capture the image which display on the monitor. But the image seem to be not displayed immediately. I also try to use your code to check whether image is set. It return True. But the image still not be displayed immediately.

Comment: @Jimi: I set Interval of the timer as the delay time. Set AutoReset as false and used Elapsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the first `Paint` event after assigning the new `Image`.
You can give it a try using a very large [image url](https://effigis.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Airbus_Pleiades_50cm_8bit_RGB_Yogyakarta.jpg)  from [this site](https://effigis.com/en/solutions/satellite-images/satellite-image-samples/).

The example uses google logo image url. Copy the following code and make sure you assign event handlers to the events:

```
bool newImageInstalled = true;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.WaitOnLoad = true;
}
private void PictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (!newImageInstalled)
    {
        newImageInstalled = true;
        BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            //Capturing the new image
            using (var bm = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width, 
                pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height))
            {
                pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bm, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
                var tempFile = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() + ".png";
                bm.Save(tempFile, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(tempFile);
            }
        }));
    }
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    newImageInstalled = false;
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = 
    "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    newImageInstalled = false;
    pictureBox1.Image = null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The Paint.event is a good idea to confirm it was painted. Finally I found the problem is caused by the camera not the program. Thank you every one and sorry about that.

Comment: No problem. Obviously timeout will work, but the post tries to answer the soonest and certain possible time to detect the image has been shown in the PictureBox. For example a very large [image](https://effigis.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Airbus_Pleiades_50cm_8bit_RGB_Yogyakarta.jpg) like this or even larger images take long to load into PictureBox.